# awk/sed/grep extract part of lines with specific pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract definite part of a file such as below:

```
1443113312 mongo client connection created with mongodb://172.28.128.5:27017
1443113312 [OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 4864.0
1443113313 [READ], Return=0, 485
1443113313 [CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 4487.0
1443113314 [UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 27743.0
```

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=OVERALL 1443113312
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=READ    1443113313
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=CLEANUP 1443113313
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=UPDATE  1443113314
```

I really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: explain the algorithm you want to use to transform that input to that output. Pseudo-code would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[][ \t:]+' '/mongodb/{a=$(NF-2)":"$(NF-1);next} a{printf "%s Operations=%-7s %s\n",a,$2,$1}' file
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=OVERALL 1443113312
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=READ    1443113313
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=CLEANUP 1443113313
mongodb://172.28.128.5 Operations=UPDATE  1443113314
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[][ \t:]+'`

  This sets the field separator to any combination of spaces, tabs, colons, or square brackets (`[]`).
- `/mongodb/{a=$(NF-2)":"$(NF-1);next}`

  If the line contains `mongodb`, then we save the third and second to last fields in the variable `a`.
- `a{printf "%s Operations=%-7s %s\n",a,$2,$1}`

  If the variable `a` has been assigned a value, then print out the current reformatted as per the question.

#### Variation

This produces the mongo string but not IP and puts the operation in parens:

```
$ awk -F'[][ \t:]+' '/mongodb/{a=$(NF-2);next} a{printf "%s\tOperations=\"%s\"\t%s\n",a,$2,$1}' file
mongodb Operations="OVERALL"    1443113312
mongodb Operations="READ"       1443113313
mongodb Operations="CLEANUP"    1443113313
mongodb Operations="UPDATE"     1443113314
```

Comment: Thanks. I spent sometime on learning sed although at the the end I was totally confused. I found awk more comprehensible.

Comment: Just a simple modification. What if I want to only get "mongodb" string without IP and put the operation value inside double quotation like Operation="READ" !?

Comment: @Araz Very good: I added a variation that eliminated the IP and put quotes around the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -nwe 'if (m=mongo client connection created with (mongodb://[0-9.]+)=) {
               $url = $1;
           } elsif (/^([0-9]+) \[([[:upper:]]+)\]/) {
               print "$url Operations=$2 $1\n";
           }' input-file
```

Explanation: `-n` reads the input line by line. Each time the "created" string is encountered, the URL is saved in the $url variable. Each time a number (timestamp?) plus upper case word in square brackets is encountered, the URL with the action and timestamp are printed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & printf):

```
sed -rn '\|://|h;G;s/^(\S+) \[(\S+)\].* (\S+):.*/printf "%s Operations=%-7s %s" \3 \2 \1/ep' file
```

This use GNU sed's `e` flag which evaluates the pattern space. Alternatively the evaluation can be done in a separate process by piping the `printf` commands to a shell, so:

```
sed -rn '\|://|h;G;s/^(\S+) \[(\S+)\].* (\S+):.*/printf "%s Operations=%-7s %s\n" \3 \2 \1/p' | sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution :)