# awk/sed/grep modify lines with certain pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to modify the file below in a certain way:

```
1445777609670355400 mongo client connection created with mongodb
1445777612279125121 [A], Time(ms), 3344.0
1445777612288777627 [B], Throughput(ops/sec), 299.0430622009569
1445777612289907122 [C], Operations, 505.0
1445777612290864948 [D], AverageLatency(us), 1712.0039603960397
1445777612294065941 [E], MinLatency(us), 253.0
1445777612325747187 [F], Return=0, 505
```

I followed solution given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937736/awk-sed-grep-extract-part-of-lines-with-specific-pattern). I got some results so far:

```
mongodb operations="A" 1445777612279125121
mongodb operations="B" 1445777612288777627
mongodb operations="C" 1445777612289907122
mongodb operations="D" 1445777612290864948
mongodb operations="E" 1445777612294065941
mongodb operations="F" 1445777612295131996
```

I'd like to achieve this output:

```
mongodb operations="A",RunTime(ms)=3344.0 1445777612279125121
mongodb operations="B",Throughput(ops/sec)=299.0430622009569 1445777612288777627
mongodb operations="C",Operations=505.0 1445777612289907122
mongodb operations="D",AverageLatency(us)=1712.0039603960397 1445777612290864948
mongodb operations="E",MinLatency(us)=253.0 1445777612294065941
mongodb operations="F",Return=505 1445777612325747187
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most beautiful solution, but this should do the trick

```
awk -F"[][, ]+" '{str=$3; sub(/Time/,"RunTime", str); \
                  sub(/=0/, "", str); \
                  if(NR>1){print "mongodb operations=\""$2"\","str"="$4,$1}}' input
```

In this solution, the first two words `mongodb operations` are hard coded. Due to your desired output, two string substitutions had to be included (Time -> RunTime and Return=0 -> Return)

Comment: You don't need any of the trailing semicolons, nor the backslashes at the end of the first 2 lines, and if you move the test on NR earlier you can avoid doing unnecessary sub()s on the first line. Also if you lose the `if` and move the test into the condition section instead of having it in the action section, it'll be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][[:space:],]+" }
NR>1 {
    sub(/^Time/,"Run&",$3)
    sub(/=[0-9]+$/,"",$3)
    printf "mongodb operations=\"%s\",%s=%s %s\n",$2,$3,$4,$1
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
mongodb operations="A",RunTime(ms)=3344.0 1445777612279125121
mongodb operations="B",Throughput(ops/sec)=299.0430622009569 1445777612288777627
mongodb operations="C",Operations=505.0 1445777612289907122
mongodb operations="D",AverageLatency(us)=1712.0039603960397 1445777612290864948
mongodb operations="E",MinLatency(us)=253.0 1445777612294065941
mongodb operations="F",Return=505 1445777612325747187
```